# bashrc alias starts application on terminal start

Tags: bash, atom-editor

I have a portable installation of atom running on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I like to be able to execute it like it would be a normal installation:

`atom <some filename>`

Defining

`alias atom='~/atom/atom-1.14.4-amd64/atom'`

in my terminal works fine. But I dont want to add that after each restart. So I added it to my .bash_aliases. Only Problem is, that now every time I start my Terminal, a new instace of atom is starting and my terminal shows:

`bash: complete: ~/atom/atom-1.14.4-amd64/atom: no completion specification`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding it as alias , softlink the path of atom to some existing PATH directories.In most cases /usr/bin will be the part of PATH so try the following command

```
sudo ln -s ~/atom/atom-1.14.4-amd64/atom /usr/bin/
```